# mysqli_affected_rows() when update

Tags: php

I have a trouble in this code, can anybody help?:(
There's my code:

```
$query = "UPDATE subjects SET
              menu_name = '{$menu_name}',
              position = {$position},
              visible = {$visible}
              WHERE id = {$id}";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows() == 1) {
      $message = "The subject was successfully updated.";
    } else {
      $message = "The subject update failed.";
      $message .= "<br>" . mysqli_error();
    }

  } else {
    $message = "There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
  }
```

Comment: Try to use PDO and PDOException instead of mysqli directly so you will know which is exactly error

Comment: where i should place the PDO and PDOException?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: mysqli_affected_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Learn about PDO: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_affected_rows();
```

> Connection Required. Specifies the MySQL connection to use

Change your code to

```
mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
```

Comment: I've tried it, but doesn't work too, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows( **$result** == 1)
```

Use `$result` variable in the bracket.